# Converting from ADC to real voltage

Tags: voltage, adc, voltage-divider

I would need to calculate initial voltage from ADC reading.

I'm a bit confused from the 3.3 V after the voltage divider.
Basically I have a voltage can vary from -12 V to +12 V on input and ADC is reading values from 0 to 4095.
This means theoretically that nearly 0 is -12 V, 2047 is point 0 V, 4095 is 12 V.

In reality I'm getting weird values as it seems the ADC is not linear. Maybe I'm using the wrong formula to convert? How should it be converted then?

[image]

| voltage | ideal ADC reading |
| --- | --- |
| -12 V | 0 |
| 0 V | 2047 |
| +12 V | 4095 |

Comment: It won't be linear because of the resistor to the 3.3v. Take that out if you want to measure the 12v inputs.

Comment: @user1850479 a resistor won't change linearity. The 56k + 66k provide a Thevenin voltage of about half rail and 30k to bias the potted down 12 into the 0-3 V range.

Comment: Sorry, I missed the -12v minimum and thought he was trying to measure only positive values. Ignore that remark.

Comment: 'I'm getting weird values' doesn't give us much to go on. Put a table in your question of voltages and readings, at least 5 of each, the more the better. Better still, edit the one I've started for you, changing the second column to 'actual ADC values'

Comment: Which ADC you are using? Via which interface? How is the ADC configured? If ADC is built in to MCU, which MCU you are using?

Comment: hello, I'm using an esp32 and I'm getting weird values too. Seems like +/12V are correct but as I go near 0 I'm getting weird .this is why I think I'm wrong in calculation for the 3.3v attached resistor. My ADC output a 8.7V is 3138 , at 5.7v is 2560, at 2.8v is 2120. more you go near "zero" more it slow measurement. Looks kind of logarithmic formula but I repeat, I know how to calculate the normale voltage divider but maybe there's different calculation for the involved 3.3v resistor.

Comment: Like Neil_UK suggested, if you look at it with Thevenin's you can get the equation you're after: \$V_{OUT} = \left ( 3.3+\left ( 56000*\left ( \frac{V_{1}-3.3}{256000} \right ) \right ) \right )*0.603175\$ Where \$V_{1}\$ is your ADC input. So the readings you're getting are about right

Comment: I suggest reading an application note on sources of ADC errors. https://www.analog.com/en/technical-articles/the-abcs-of-analog-to-digital-converters-how-adc-errors-affect-system-performance.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ESP32 has a free ADC, so it's good ADC value for money, but it is a markedly bad "12-bit" ADC.

I suggest you avoid the top and bottom regions of the range (100mV or so at the chip).

This is complicated by the fact that the actual Expressif ADC input works from a nominal 0 to 1.1V or so (but it could be 0 to 1.0V or 0 to 1.2V because the reference is not tightly specified). So you are using a module that has some resistors on it (another voltage divider), which will affect your voltage divider calculations.

Then there is reference tolerance (+/-10%), power supply tolerance (used for offset) of maybe +/-5%, resistor tolerances of a few percent in total. If you try to calibrate it by applying a voltage that causes the reading to saturate (0 or 4095) the calibration will be invalid. You might try +/-10V in for calibration.

Comment: This was the problem!! I changed the 200k resistor with a 300k resistor and now I can correctly read the values. means the ESP32 is buggy!!

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to see if the ADC is producing the values you expect is to set up a test harness, like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fsUDuK.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Here you may present the ADC with any potential from -12V to +12V, selected with a potentiometer. By measuring the actual ADC input potential with a voltmeter, VM1, and comparing that with the ADC conversion result, you may determine if the ADC is the problem.

In your case, the network of resistors is certainly not producing anything in the range -12V to +12V, and I am not sure what that network has to do with this problem. Just measure the ADC's *actual* input potential, and see what the ADC says is there.

With all that out of the way, I would point out that your understanding of what ADC result should correspond to -12V, 0V and +12V may be incorrect. If the ADC uses [two's complement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1049722/what-is-twos-complement) to represent the voltage, then what you should expect is:

000000000000: 0V

011111111111: +12V

100000000000: -12V

Maybe that's what's making your numbers *look* wrong, when actually they are correct.